# I'm trying to create a circular array using a vector, is there a manual away to accomplish this?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to create a circular vector array starting at some value counting through to the end.
I have some vector initialized to N, I want to run through it M times, starting at a value s.
say n = 9, I want to start at s = 2, so the print out would be '2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1'

```
int index1 = 0;
vector<int> index(n);
for(int I = s; I <=m; I++)
{
 index[index1] = I; 
 index1++
 if(index1 == n)
 index1 = 0;
}
```

then displaying the values down below, also the 5th line can I just assign that to vector as the starting value? Or would I have to do 'index.push_back(index1)' ?

I am fairly new I have read a little about the rotate function, but I wonder is there a way to do it this way. Thank you for the input

Comment: Please show a [mcve] including expected vs. actual output

Comment: Are you looking for a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)? This can be achieved with a `std::array` or `std::vector`. You have to manage additional indices for start and stop of contents. Modulus ([operator%()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/multiplicative-operators-and-the-modulus-operator)) might be worth to be mentioned as well.